# How can I get the "tr id" from HTML code?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to use VBA for taking the URL adress of diferent links from a web page, but without success. Has anyone any idea why my code don't work?

My code is below:

```
Sub Test() 
Dim URL As String 
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer 
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument 
Dim dictObj As Object: Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
Dim tRowID As String 

URL = "http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/"; 
With IE 
    .Navigate URL 
    .Visible = True Do Until 
    .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop Set HTMLdoc = .Document 
End With 
With HTMLdoc 
    Set tblSet = .getElementById("fs-results") 
    Set mTbl = tblSet.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(1) 
    Set tRows = mTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With dictObj 
        For Each tRow In tRows 
            tRowID = Mid(tRow.getAttribute("id"), 5) 
            If Not .Exists(tRowID) Then .Add tRowID, Empty 
            End If 
        Next tRow 
    End With 
End With 
For Each Key In dictObj 
    Debug.Print Key 
Next Key 
Set IE = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: tRow.ID should work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description of your problem.  What happens when you run your code?  Have you tried setting break points to check which parts actually execute?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: It works! Thank you very much for your help!